# What is required to keep the peace (for now) with a fallen empire?

Tags: stellaris

i'm still in my first game of stellaris (which is my first paradox game so this question might seem silly to experienced grand strategy buffs but i've just switched from civ:be to stellaris) and i wonder what might trigger a violent reaction from the fallen empire (except declaring war on them, obviously)... to avoid exactly that.

the fallen ones are fanatic xenophiles but neither pacifistic nor militaristic and a couple of smaller campaigns against other "regular" empires didn't seem to bother them (my standing with them remained pretty much unchanged).

but as the game progresses i'm getting worried that they might become hostile because i might do something stupid that sets them off, so any hints/experiences regarding diplomacy with fallen empire would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are four types of Fallen Empire, and each one has different things that anger them, based on their ethics.

*Keepers of Knowledge (Fanatic Materialists)*: The Fallen Empire dedicates itself to the hoarding of technologies that it believes should be kept out of the hands of young and irresponsible races. Pursuing dangerous lines of research will draw their ire. (*Technologies considered "dangerous" are marked in red*)

> Notably, AI and Jump Drives

*Enigmatic Observers (Fanatic Xenophiles)*: Empires that use slaves, or purge populations may suffer the wrath of the Observers.

*Holy Guardians (Fanatic Spiritualists)*: This fallen empire dedicates itself to the preservation and defense of its holy sites. Colonizing systems that they consider sacred is likely to incur their ire.

*Militant Isolationists (Fanatic Xenophobe)*: The fallen empire dedicates itself to the defense of its borders against any intrusions. Colonizing systems that border them is likely to draw their ire.

Other things, such as insulting, rivalling them or declaring war (obviously) will anger them as well.

Fallen empires may also make requests or demands of you, and refusing to comply can reduce their opinion, whereas complying will increase it.

If you have the Synthetic Dawn DLC, there is a fifth kind of Fallen Empire: *Ancient Caretakers (Machine Intelligence)*. The Caretakers are normally quite passive and won't object to anything you do short of actually declaring war on them. They will occasionally request permission to inoculate your population against an unspecified disease (this has random effects), or ask you to change your policies in various ways, but they don't mind if you refuse.

> The Ancient Caretakers are the guardians against the AI Contingency disaster. If this happens, there is a 2/3 chance the Caretakers will awaken to help fight it; but a 1/3 chance that their firewalls fail and they start attacking everything instead. Obviously, depending on your own handling of the Contingency, this can bring the Caretakers into conflict or alliance with your nation.

[Source: Stellaris Wiki](https://stellaris.paradoxwikis.com/Fallen_empire)

Comment: thanks for the clarification... this bit of information is something that i would have expected to find somewhere ingame but i guess i'll just have to get used to checking the wiki in the future :S

Comment: I think if you mouse over their empire type in the diplomacy screen, it'll also give you this information there]

Comment: To elaborate on those vague descriptions based on what's happened to me in-game: Keepers of Knowledge hate it when you research AI. Haven't had a problem with Observers or Isolationists yet. Guardians hate it when you colonize tomb worlds. You can't trade with fallen empires, but you can establish an embassy.

Comment: To elaborate further: AI or Jump Drives (and tech considered dangerous is highlighted in red). I'm not sure Guardians specifically revere tomb worlds, but a planet will have a modifier telling you if it's a holy site

Answer (score 6):

In my current game I was surrounded by two *Militant Isolationists* empires. I could expand right next to their borders without any problems but only by keeping up **an embassy** in both realms. Kept their happiness at around -30 which is way above the required -75.

Comment: I have a game where I have taken around 60% of one of those (isolationist) empires. Embassy and I am STILL at -20. No war.